# What type of code should I use to insert some strings in a string?

Tags: python

I want to insert some strings in a string.

All I know is that there are four ways to do this, here are four examples:

```py
query = "What type of code should I use to insert some strings in a string?"

category = "Python"

query_category = "".join(["Query: ", query, " Category: ", category])
```

or

```py
query = "What type of code should I use to insert some strings in a string?"

category = "Python"

query_category = "Query: " + query + " Category: " + category
```

or

```py
query = "What type of code should I use to insert some strings in a string?"

category = "Python"

query_category = f"Query: {query} Category: {category}"
```

or

```py
query = "What type of code should I use to insert some strings in a string?"

category = "Python"

query_category = "Query: {query} Category: {category}".format(query = query, category = category)
```

What type of code should I use to insert some strings in a string? Can anyone explain the pros and cons of each code?

Comment: Seems like f-strings are the simplest and cleanest way to do it.

Comment: @JohnGordon do you mean the third way I said?

Comment: I think concatenating strings with plus is the normal practice.

Comment: Yes, f-strings are the third example.

Comment: 3, if your python version supports f-strings, otherwise, 1.

Comment: @Meerkat I know, but online articles say that using `+` is slow and using `"".join` is faster. Is it faster to use `"".join`?

Comment: `+` is slow, if you do it _over and over and over_, like in a loop that executes thousands of times.  You don't have to worry about that here.

Comment: Way back in ancient history, like Python 1, `+` was slow and it was important to use `join`.  The difference is no longer very important, except in special cases.  You are guilty of premature optimization here, wasting time on relatively unimportant issues.  First, make it work in a way that makes sense to you.  THEN decide if it is fast enough.

Comment: I always use f-strings. This is more clear to me. Choose your own way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer

You should use f-strings (third way).

f-strings are more readable, concise, and less error-prone than other means. In my test (test speed). Using f-strings is the fastest way.

#### Long answer

f-strings are a great way to format strings. Not only are they more readable, concise, and less error-prone than the alternatives, they're also faster!

##### Simple Syntax

The syntax is similar to what you would do with `str.format()`, but less verbose. Of the four ways, it's the easiest to read, right?

Using an uppercase letter for `f` (`F`) is also possible:

```py
query_category = F"Query: {query} Category: {category}"
```

##### Arbitrary Expressions

Because f-strings are evaluated at runtime, you can put any and all valid Python expressions into them. This allows you to do some nifty things.

You can do something very simple like this:

```py
nine_times_nine = f"{9 * 9}"
```

Functions can also be called:

```
def function():
    …

call_function = f"{function()}"
```

#### Summary

f-strings are the perfect way to use them. For more information, check out this [article](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).